# EF: How to update connections in many to many relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two classes which has many-to-many relation. Messages and Recipient:

```
[Table("Messages")]
public class Message {
    //...
    public virtual List<Contact> Recipients {get; set;}
}
```

```
[Table("Contacts")]
public class Contact {
    //...
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages {get; set;}
}
```

I set up it's relation by using FluentAPI the following way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().HasMany(e => e.Messages).WithMany(e => e.Recipients)
    .Map(map => { map.ToTable("MessagesRecipients"); });
```

When I create a message object with recipients and save them to the db with `dbContext.SaveChanges();` it works perfectly. The corresponding messageID and recipientID are saved to the `MessagesRecipients` table. The problem comes when I try to modify the recipients collection in a message (add a new - or remove an existing recipient). Nothing happens in the `MessagesRecipients` table. I would expect to update the connections as well not just the message itself.

I get the message from the database with eager loading.

What am I missing to achieve the expected behavior?

Comment: Unluckly Entity Framework does not support N to N relations...
You have do manage them manually.

Comment: okay, so for example with queries?